# make duplicate elements if their number is less than 4 and they are not empty

Tags: php, yii2

I have a slider for scrolling through images, and I add all the images to the slider through php

The situation is that the slider needs at least 4 images to work, and I wrote the corresponding code that copies and pastes the images, if we add only one or two

Here is the working code

```
<?php if (count($images) < 4) { ?>
    <?php
    $images = array_merge($images, $images);
    $images = array_merge($images, $images);
    $images = array_slice($images, 0, 4);

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if ($image->image_id) { ?>
            <div class="slider-image">
                <img src="<?= $image->url ?>" alt="<?= $image->name ?>">
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And there is this line

```
if ($image->image_id)
```

That is, I may have a situation that such an image is not in the database, and so that there are no errors, I added the appropriate check

So, if I have an image that is not in the database, then this copy code does not work, since it copies an empty image, which is then not displayed

```
$images = array_merge($images, $images);
$images = array_merge($images, $images);
$images = array_slice($images, 0, 4);
```

How can I take into account the factor that the picture is not in the database and correct the code for copying? Or do I need to use another implementation here?

Comment: If `$images` had 3 how would you decide which should be the 4th? Why not fix the slider?

Comment: if 3 then copy the first

Comment: What does it mean that "image is not in database"? Does it mean that `$images` array is empty or that there is some `$image` model where only `image_id` property is empty?

Comment: @MichalHynčica there is an $image model, but image_id is null and accordingly $image->url does not exist

Comment: Maybe swap `foreach ($images as $image) {` with `for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){ if($images[$i]->image_id) { ?>` then `} else {...<div class="slider-image">...$images[0]->image_id....}`? because `0` (1) should always exist, right?

Comment: Why all the starting and stopping of PHP in a simple stream of PHP. Makes reading it most unpleasant

Comment: I think you are saying you are loading the `$images` array from the database. So if there is no rows in the database for this situation, what can you do, I would suggest a default image, or images set of 4

Comment: @user3783243 I just didn’t quite understand how to do it right through the `for` loop, I had too many elements copied. Can you please elaborate on this in your answer?

Comment: You said it was possible for there to be NO entries in the `$images` array, so first you need to check if you have `>1 and <4` then you can dup. But if you have `0` you have to go get some default images

Comment: @RiggsFolly There are `$images` entries anyway, just not a specific `image_id` field, and because of this, empty entries are copied

Comment: Don't make copies, you don't need them. Iterate 4 times and pull the index of the array in the iteration. If array is empty show the default.

Comment: @user3783243 I don't quite understand what to do with array indexes

Comment: How about you show us the oputput from a `var_dump($images);` done just before that first IF

Comment: Rough idea https://3v4l.org/eWMUY example with less than 4 images https://3v4l.org/fsZKj We need to see what you actually have though to put a real answer together

Comment: @user3783243 I checked, and when I have 4 images, one of them is empty, then everything works well, the last image is copied. But when I have 2 images and one of them is epmty, I get this error `Undefined offset: 2`

Comment: @Hector I don't know what that means. Again shows what you have.

Comment: @user3783243 figured out that error is gone, but now there is another problem, if you add 5 or more images, then only the first 4 will be displayed, but it is necessary that all be

Comment: @user3783243 look at the example https://3v4l.org/pGaP7, in fact I have 4 objects, but one of them is empty, and because of this there will be no copying, what can be done in such a situation?

Comment: @user3783243 if I remove the `if (count($images) < 4)` check, then I will always display only 4 images, and I need 5 or more images to be displayed all of a sudden

Comment: @Hector This is why it has been requested multiple times to provide what you are working with. :( Shows us what you have so we can help. In your example link there are only 4 elements. The `count` check shouldn't be needed.. maybe https://3v4l.org/Dsp3P

Comment: @user3783243 
it's just that if there are 3 objects now, then the output will be 3, but I need to display at least 4

Comment: @user3783243 I do not need to copy an empty object, I need to copy objects only if there are less than 4 objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume your `$images` is not empty and is a regular list (has sequental zero-based indices). Just populate the images array in the loop as:

```php
$images = [0,1];
$i = 0;
while( count( $images ) < 4 )
    $images[] = $images[ $i++ ];


print_r($images); # [0,1,0,1]


/*
For given initial arrays we will get following results:

[0] -> [0,0,0,0]
[0,1] -> [0,1,0,1]
[0,1,2] -> [0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,3] -> [0,1,2,3]
*/
```

If you have some dummy images objects - filter them out first:

```php
$images = array_filter($images, fn($image) => !empty($image->image_id) );
```

Comment: @user3783243 reason? I don't think PHP really counts array elements every time instead of just exposing internal counter that is updated every time array is modified. Made a small test that shows no difference for 1K, 1M and 10M arrays.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the `while` and `for` iterations have different logic applied. `for` what that evaluator does count very iteration.. this approach doesnt though. Strange, manual has it written the same but https://3v4l.org/24bbM vs. https://3v4l.org/HgTZG shows what you described.

Comment: With your particular examples within the `for` you are comparing `count()` and current `$i` value, both do increase with every iteration making this loop infinite. The `while` example compares current `count()` with the static `4`. The logic differs. To make it somewhat similar, the `for` loop should be something like `for( $i = count($images); $i < 4; $i++ )`